# Add multiple event listener on google map API v3 AND MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add, for each of my markers, an event on click to center on this one. I use the lib "MarkerWithLabel" and when I click on a marker, the map is zooming on the last marker each time.

Here is my code :

```
var map         = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas')),
        bounds      = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        marker      = [],
        grafxUrl    = $('#map-canvas').data('grafx'),
        image       = {
            url : grafxUrl + 'universal/icons/pin_locator.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(24, 31),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 31)
        };

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].fLatitude, response[i].fLongitude),
            map: map,
            icon : image ,
            title : (i+1)+' '+response[i].sName,
            labelContent: (i+1),
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 25),
            labelClass: "markerNum", // the CSS class for the label
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(15);
            map.setCenter(marker.position);
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
        //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

What is wrong with my script ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `marker` is defined as an array but then you are using it as a simple variable (`marker = ...`). What I would do: `var markers = [];` (note the **s** in marker**s**) then `var marker = new MarkerWithLabel ...` then `markers.push(marker)` if you aim to keep each marker in an array for further reference.

Comment: It don't change anything. Still zooming on the last marker set :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example on how to extend a bounds object to display all markers on the map.

```
function initialize() {

    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(40.744656, -74.005966);
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243685);
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the bounds object
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Create random markers
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        // Calculate a random position
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                map.setZoom(5);
                map.setCenter(marker.position);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Extend the bounds with the last marker position
        bounds.extend(position);
    }

    // Fit map to the extended bounds    
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

initialize();
```

This creates 100 random markers within the defined bounds (southWest / northEast coords) then extends a bounds object and finally fit the map to this bounds object. See how the marker variable is defined (within the for loop) and how the `fitBounds()` is called (outside the for loop). The same should apply to your code.

Below is a **working demo**. Hope this helps!

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ay337bwp/)</kbd>

Comment: It's not changing anything ... still zooming on the last marker

Comment: Whoops... my bad. I didn't test that part. You need a closure in the event listener for this. Answer code & fiddle updated!